# Django: write data to mySQL server from command line

Tags: django

I have a django web interface but it will mainly for users to query, view results and can edit to add or delete.
But my data each time write to server alot, so I want to supply users command line so that they can embedded inside their script to send data. Before I use mysql direct command line but then the server not not allow to do that, user cannot access direct to database. HOw can I do this? I heard some one say using REST, is it? and how it look like? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're so daring as to allow a mysql command line in one of your UIs (I'm not).  You may be better off allowing input of [fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures).

I've done this other ways as well.  In some instances, I have a CSV upload function, that will take a specifically formatted CSV file, upload it to the server, and pass it off to a background task (via Celery) and add/update records in the DB when valid data is presented.

Comment: But my users are total blind about django, they use my django web to view their data and I can give them a command to write data within their scripts. for it seem need csv and python loadata .. and somemore the server is restrict from seeing or interact with it

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm having trouble with the language barrier between us.  I don't really understand all of your requirements.